# Loading dropdown options dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the html I have a select tag with three optrions and clicking on the third option I want to load few more options into the dropdown...
Here is the code:

```
<select id="title">
    <option val="0">Mr.</option>
    <option val="1">Mrs.</option>
    <option val="2">Others</option>
</select>
```

So clicking on 'others' I want to load some more options in the dropdown removing 'others' from the dropdown ..how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#title").change(function(event){
    var selected = $(event.target).val();
    if (selected === "2")
    {
        $(event.target).children("[value='2']").remove();
        $(event.target).append("<option value='3'>Other one</option>");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPupj/7/)

**To keep a dropdown opened (not elegant)**:

```
$("#title").change(function(event){
    $(event.target).attr('size', 1);
    var selected = $(event.target).val();
    if (selected === "2")
    {
        $(event.target).children("[value='2']").remove();
        $(event.target).append("<option value='3'>Other one</option>");
        $(event.target).attr('size', $(event.target).children().length);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPupj/8/

Click event on **select** doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: The above code works but I want to keep the dropdown open on adding new options..

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/vvHZ3/1/

```
$("#others").click(function(){
    $('#others').hide();
    $("#title").append("<option value=\"Any\" >item</option>");});
```

Comment: the above jsfiddle is not working for me

Comment: @Ashok recheck i have tested it.It works

Comment: This is not working in chrome, in IE new option is adding but 'Others' is not hiding

Comment: @Ashok i tested it on mozilla not on chrome.I wasnt knowing that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is javascript like

```
<select id="title" onchange="DDOnChange(this)">
    <option val="0">Mr.</option>
    <option val="1">Mrs.</option>
    <option val="2">Others</option>
</select>

DDOnChange = function DDOnChange(obj)
{
    if (obj.value == 'Others')
    {
        var option1=document.createElement("option");
        option1.text="Others1";
        var option2=document.createElement("option");
        option2.text="Others2";
        obj.add(option1,null);
        obj.add(option2,null);
        obj.remove(obj.selectedIndex);
    }
}
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdHTq/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('#title').on('change',function()
           {
               if(this.value == 'Others');
               {
                  $('#ot').remove();
                  $('#title').append(' <option val="2">Your 1 option</option>');
               }
           });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q8CYC/2/)

Comment: the value is '2', not 'others'

Comment: hello downvoters check fiddle OP not give value ok

Comment: alert(this.value) what you get mr @GalV reply..

Comment: sorry, you're right. `this.value` gets the text

Comment: the reason is Op made mistake he just put val

Comment: hi sridhar,ur code works but the newly added one gets selected by itself..i dont want that...I want the new options in the dropdown and allow user to select from them

Comment: k i updated code and fiddle check @user2541753